# How to copy and rename files based on a txt file from directory and subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I made a batch file that allows me to copy and rename (in that order) files based on a txt or csv-file. In column 1, there is the original filename, in column 2 the new name. This allows me to copy and rename only the files that I need.

It works very fine, but it has a limitation: for now I can only copy files from one directory, the main directory. I would like to be able to only copy the files, independently if they are in the main or its subdirectories. In other words, it should search the files in both the main directory and subdirectories.

Below the code:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%j in (basefile.txt) do (
copy "%%j" destinationfolder/%%k
)
```

I have looked and tried combinations with /r or /s etc.

It is probably some easy addition, but I just can't figure it out...
Thanks

Comment: How do you generate your CSV file?  Why not add the paths in there when generating the file?

Comment: you want to rename files in recursive manner? if your able to use java i can write script for you..

Comment: Hi @Foxidrive, It consists mainly of images. So people request images of products that I automatically translate to existing file/imagenames. Since the images are scattered in different folders, I would like to extract them from the 'database' to 1 folder without manually having to search for them.

Therefor I can't know beforehand what the path will be...

Comment: @Dilip I'm looking for anything I can work with ;) As far as I know, I can execute java-files, but not compile them if that's what you mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should copy the files in the folder tree to the destination.

It's not perfect as a false match is possible if the filespec is not unique, and matches within the short filenames are possible too if the filename is not specific enough.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%j in (basefile.txt) do (
 for /r "d:\base\folder"  %%a in ("%%j") do (
    copy "%%a" "d:\destinationfolder\%%k"
 )
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly indeed! Thanks!

The filenames are always unique, so no problem there!